# how do you handle outliers of different sizes in different columns?

Tags: data-analysis, data-cleaning, outliers

I am analyzing dailyActivity_merged.csv and sleepDay_merged.csv from the Fitabase data. When cleaning the data, I checked the data for outliers. And as you can see, there are many outliers of different sizes in different columns. I'm afraid to delete them column by column so as not to alter the results. How should I handle these outliers? Is it necessary to delete them?[boxplot of different columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbfEn.png)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having outliers in your data as they also represent the daily activities. In fact, removing them would create a manipulated data set that would give a misrepresented representation of what you are analyzing. How to handle outliers is based on what you are going to do with the data in general. For example if you are doing regression you could use RMSE loss instead of the normal MSE so your model won't get "thrown off" by outliers

Comment: Thank you @NaphatAmundsen you're right. I didn't see it in this way. I will reconsider my approach.